# Possible to get the user location while on mobile browser google maps api?

Tags: android, iphone, google-maps

Is it possible to get the users location with google maps api when they (through their mobile browser, not an app or their own google maps) visit your website on their phone? and your website has google maps and geolocation. 
im only interrested in android, iphone right now if it differs from the other OS.